# Passing string with "+" sing from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm passing a string, that contains plus signs (+), from jsp page to servlet, but in the servlet, the string has blank spaces instead of "+".

JSP code:

```
     var data = {Certificate:"KgAwIBAgIQQ+1b5xQKgN0HfjIAPy+vdjANBg",Id:10043};
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "Assinatura",
           data: 'signStart=' + JSON.stringify(data)
       });
```

Servlet code:

```
request.getParameter("signStart"); //KgAwIBAgIQQ 1b5xQKgN0HfjIAPy vdjANBg
```

I know I could replace the spaces on server side, but was wandering if there is a better solution.

Comment: You can try to use `%2B` instead of `+`.

Comment: Are you appropriately URL-encoding your data on the sending side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the string while passing it to Servlet in your ajax request. You can use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Assinatura",
    data: 'signStart=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data))
});
```

or you can pass `data` as Object, instead of String:

```
data: {'signStart': JSON.stringify(data)}
```

Answer (score 5):

Characters like "+" needs to be encoded when passing through URL